# Symfony 2 form checkbox checked based on entity data?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

ok I have built a Form Type for my accounts entity and within that I have an *entity type* field for my what panels that account is entitled to have, the following almost works,

```
    $Results = $options['data']->getResellerPanelOps()->toArray(); <- this is where I get my data from!

    ->add('panels', 'entity',    ['label'    => 'Panels',
                                      'class'    => 'Bundle:Panels',
                                      'choice_label' => 'panels.Title',
                                      'multiple' => true,
                                      'expanded' => true,
                                      'required' => false,
                                      'mapped'   => false,
                                      'attr'     => ['class' => 'Panels'],
                                      'query_builder' =>  function(EntityRepository $er) use ($Results) {
                                                                  return $er->createQueryBuilder('s')
                                                                            ->where("s.id IN (:ids)")
                                                                            ->setParameter('ids', $Results);
                                                              }
                                         ]);
```

So this lists all the panels has checkboxes that account already has, however when there are no panels already added to that account, it displays nothing.

What I really want is for it to display all panels from an preset array (or the entity that lists them all). But I am not sure how to do that? So all the preset data is from *panel_details* and the list of what user has access to is held within *panels*

The way I am thinking is that I change the class of `panels` to `panel_details`, but then my `choice_label` will be wrong, not sure how to execute that change?

I think I have explained myself right in this question but please do point out if it does not make any sense.

All help most welcome.

Many Thanks

Comment: is `panels` a separate entity? if so, make a form type for it and use a `collection` those panels that the owning entity is related to.

Comment: yes they are separate entities. you know I have been banging my head on the wall for an idea, not once did I think about collections - I have a look, thanks

Comment: good luck with it :)

Comment: Thanks, I am still getting my head around Symfony 2 a little and collections are still one of these things I still dont use much... but I give it a go, thanks mate